# AWS API Gateway always generate body encoded by base64 into Lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless

I am making API endpoint using Serverless, Lambda/API Gateway. But the request body is always encoded by base64. What is the reason?

Comment: Have u set respective body template ? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html

Comment: Provide sample data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't set respective body template. I want to get JSON data without setting respective body template.

I believe it's because of Lambda Proxy Integration.

Just solved problem with this.

```
let buff = Buffer.from(event.body, "base64");
let eventBodyStr = buff.toString('UTF-8');
let eventBody = JSON.parse(eventBodyStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

ApiGateway is set to have base64encode property as true by default , you can avoid to encode the body sending the correct content-type header example content-type : application/json

[source here](https://aws.amazon.com/es/blogs/compute/handling-binary-data-using-amazon-api-gateway-http-apis/)